# Stateful servie with minimum downtime

Tags: kubernetes

How to implement stateful service with minimal downtime?

I am not sure if a stateful set with replica count=1 is suitable choice due to possibility of downtime during updates.

Is the following possible in k8, or maybe there is a better way to achieve the same result:

It is OK to have more then one instance of stateful process alive at the same time, as long as only one (or zero) instance is active at at any time.

Use regular (non-stateful) deployment with replica count 1. Two instances may be alive for some time during update, that is when k8 waits for new instance to become ready before terminating the old one. When the old instance is terminated (or responds OK to STOP method), the new instance is notified via START method to become active.

Is is possible to configure a deployment, so that k8 calls STOP/START methods at appropriate times?

Comment: The overall path you describe sounds like a normal Deployment rollout, but that only works for stateless workloads.  What you describe may not actually be possible.  (How will your application react if the two replicas are trying to use the same filesystem state?  Do you have any storage implementation that could be mounted on multiple nodes at the same time?)  Can you run a stateless replicated workload, backed by something like a database in a StatefulSet that rarely needs to be restarted?